# Почему картинки не в ряд?

Tags: html, css

У меня три картинки съехали в низ, нужно, что было в ряд [код](http://codepen.io/Incub/pen/MyoQJL)

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="mid">
        <div class="slider__img">
            <img src="img/monitorcenter.png" class="mcenter" alt="">
            <img src="img/monitorleft.png" class="mleft" alt="">-
            <img src="img/monitorright.png"  class="mright" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что они не могут поместиться в контейнере `div.slider__img` по ширине, сделайте маргины и паддинги меньше - поместятся

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так)

```
<style>
.mcenter, .mleft, .mright{
   max-width: 33%;
}
</style>

<div class="slider">
<div class="mid">
    <div class="slider__img">
        <p>
           <img src="img/monitorcenter.png" class="mcenter" alt="">
           <img src="img/monitorleft.png" class="mleft" alt="">-
           <img src="img/monitorright.png"  class="mright" alt="">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте для всех картинок `float:left`, и одинаковый отступ сверху